# Combine nested query with filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ES 2.1 and have the following mapping:

```
"startDate": {
  "type": "date", 
  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS||yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
  "index": "not_analyzed", 
  "store": true
},"identities": {
  "type": "nested",
  "properties": {
    "identityatt": { "type": "integer", "index": "not_analyzed", "store": true },
    "identitykey": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed", "store": true },
    "identityval": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed", "store": true },
    "identitytype": { "type": "integer", "index": "not_analyzed", "store": true }
  }
}
```

The following queries are fine and they return what I expect:

```
{ "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "startDate": {
            "from": "2016-02-19 11:11:25",
            "to": "2016-02-27 11:11:25",
            "include_lower": true,
            "include_upper": true
          }
}}}}}
```

this one filters by a time range, and with the next I want to retrieve all with a special identity type

```
{
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "identities",
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "identities.identitytype": "2"
        }
}}}}
```

But I don't seem to get a query combining those two to work.

I tried adding the time range query to the filters within the nested one, wrapping both filters within nested into a bool filter, I also tried with `filtered` query, but no luck to combine those two either.

Looking at the sample at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html , it also contains a range query, but the difference is that it's within the nested object, and my `startDate` is not contained within my nested object.

Any thoughts on how to combine those queries?

**EDIT**

I also tried what is proposed here: [Combined non-Nested and Nested Query in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577474/combined-non-nested-and-nested-query-in-elasticsearch?rq=1) and get the error `"No query registered for [filter]"`

```
{
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
  "bool": {
  "must": [
  {"filter": {
        "range": {
          "startDate": {
            "from": "2016-02-19 11:11:25",
            "to": "2016-02-27 11:11:25",
            "include_lower": true,
            "include_upper": true
          }
        }
      }},
      {"nested": {
      "path": "identities",
      "filter": { "bool": { "must": [{
        "term": {
          "identities.identitytype": "2"
        },
        "range": {
          "startDate": {
            "from": "2016-02-19 11:11:25",
            "to": "2016-02-27 11:11:25",
            "include_lower": true,
            "include_upper": true
          }
        }}]}
      }
    }
      }
  ]
  }}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should work. You cannot nest the `range` query inside the `nested` one, you need to keep it outside but at the same level in the `bool/must`.

```
{
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "startDate": {
                  "from": "2016-02-19 11:11:25",
                  "to": "2016-02-27 11:11:25",
                  "include_lower": true,
                  "include_upper": true
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "identities",
                "filter": {
                  "term": {
                    "identities.identitytype": "2"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In latest ES versions, the above query can be rewritten as follows:

```
{
  "size": 50,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "startDate": {
              "from": "2016-02-19 11:11:25",
              "to": "2016-02-27 11:11:25",
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "identities",
            "filter": {
              "term": {
                "identities.identitytype": "2"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: filtered keyword is replaced by bool in newer ES versions.

Comment: Yes, this answer provides more details about that change: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40521602/4604579